# Как получить хэш?

Tags: c++, linux, sha

Передо мной стоит задача получить sha512 из ввода пользователя. Как получить хэш в C++? Я могу использовать только openssl, не crypto++. Честно, не нашёл внятного объяснения и примеров кода, как применить тот же openssl на практике. Если sha512 на openssl нельзя получить, то хотя бы sha384 или sha256, не меньше!. Прошу пример кода с получением хэша. Используемая ОС - Linux.

Comment: И что, гугл не помог?

Comment: хз, я внятного объяснения не нашёл.

Comment: Первые же две ссылки из гугла по запросу "openssl get sha512 c++" дают вполне внятные примеры. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262386/generate-sha256-with-openssl-and-c и https://www.toptip.ca/2012/03/c-generate-sha-512-hash.html  Да, в первом примере sha256, но там разница только в названии передаваемых констант

Comment: Пробовал пример отсюда: https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2178916.html - матерится линкер. Из вашей первой ссылки - то же самое. ```ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: EVP_sha512
>>> referenced by test.c
>>>               /data/data/com.termux/files/home/tmp/test-d8024e.o:(main)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: HMAC
>>> referenced by test.c
>>>               /data/data/com.termux/files/home/tmp/test-d8024e.o:(main)
clang-13: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```

Comment: А, бл, надо было дописать ```-lcrypto```...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл это:

```
http://www.atwillys.de/content/cc/swlib-cc/include/sw/hash/crc.hh
http://www.atwillys.de/content/cc/swlib-cc/include/sw/hash/md5.hh
http://www.atwillys.de/content/cc/swlib-cc/include/sw/hash/sha1.hh
http://www.atwillys.de/content/cc/swlib-cc/include/sw/hash/sha512.hh
```

К сожалению, только для CRC, MD5, SHA1, SHA512. В коде пишем:

```
#include "sha512.hh"

...

hash = sw::sha512::calculate("Исходник"); // получаем хэш фразы
hash = sw::sha512::file("file.txt"); // хэш файла
hash = sw::sha512::calculate(&data, sizeof(data)) // хэш информации
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как примеры на голые вызовы openssl я не рекомендую ибо так плохо делать ИМХО

Для этого есть openssl EVP - https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP очень гибко под нужны

вот пример -

```
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
.....
std::string opensslCalcHashEVP(const EVP_MD *mod, const std::string &data)
{
    std::string ret;
    EVP_MD_CTX *context = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    auto on_exit = [&context](){ EVP_MD_CTX_free(context);};
    if (context != NULL)
    {
        if (EVP_DigestInit_ex(context, mod, NULL))
        {
            if (EVP_DigestUpdate(context, data.data(), data.size()))
            {
                unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
                unsigned int lengthOfHash = 0;
                if (EVP_DigestFinal_ex(context, hash, &lengthOfHash))
                {
                    ret.assign(hash, hash + lengthOfHash);
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cerr << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << std::endl;
                    on_exit();
                    throw std::runtime_error("EVP_DigestFinal_ex failed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << std::endl;
                on_exit();
                throw std::runtime_error("EVP_DigestUpdate failed");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << std::endl;
            on_exit();
            throw std::runtime_error("EVP_DigestInit_ex failed");
        }
        on_exit();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

перевод в хекс

```
std::string opensslHashToHex(const std::string &hash)
{
    static char syms[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (auto it = hash.begin(); it != hash.end(); it++)
    {
        ss << syms[((*it >> 4) & 0xf)] << syms[*it & 0xf];
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

и собственно вызовы

```
auto s256 = opensslHashToHex(opensslCalcHashEVP(EVP_sha256(), data));
auto s512 = opensslHashToHex(opensslCalcHashEVP(EVP_sha512(), data));
```

Если понадобиться то считайте и другие суммы

```
opensslHashToHex(opensslCalcHashEVP(EVP_blake2b512(), data))
opensslHashToHex(opensslCalcHashEVP(EVP_sha3_512(), data))
```

Вот что поддерживается - https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/evp.h